# how to fix boostrap 4 dropdown-menu to outside <aside>?

Tags: css

i'm create a leftbar using aside and bootstrap ,  can i show dropdown-menu to outside aside?
my current code in :
https://jsfiddle.net/q79w5zbj/3/

```
<aside>(this button dropdown)<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
</div>
```

i want dropdown-menu in outside aside , whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dropdown-menu` have  `position: absolute` base on class `dropdown` with `position: relative`. So if you want `dropdown-menu` show outside `aside`, just remove `overflow-y:hidden` in `aside` tag.

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/1hrvx9L3/